# how to prevent myControl.g.cs from overwriting with wrong base class

Tags: c#, silverlight

I've got two custom cursors for my app, MyCursor and MyOtherCursor, both of which were designed in xaml, and I added some behaviour in the xaml.cs for each of them. This behaviour was the same for both so I had them inherit from a base class to reduce code duplication.

xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.MyCursor"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Width="24" Height="24">
    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" Height="24" Width="24" Fill="White" />
</UserControl>
```

cs:

```
public partial class myCursor: CursorBase
{
    public InterchangeCursor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class CursorBase : UserControl
{
    public virtual void MoveTo(Point pt)
    {
        this.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, pt.X);
        this.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, pt.Y);
    }
}
```

There is no xaml for the base class, it's purely defined in cs.

my problem is that if I change something in the xaml for MyCursor, the MyCursor.g.cs file is regenerated, and instead of inheriting from CursorBase, the partial class in the g.cs inherits from System.Windows.Controls.UserControl. Since the other side of the partial class in the xaml.cs file still inherits CursorBase, a build error occurs. I'm finding it annoying   fixing the g.cs file each time. Does anyone know how to prevent this happening?

Comment: It shouldn't happen ...try deleting the exisiting generated folder in which all the generated files are present and build again and see.

Comment: @Malcolm I tried that, and it happened again. I suspect I'm missing something about how to inherit control behaviour in SL.

Comment: let me try on my side and see..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XAML is wrong it should be:

```
<CursorBase x:Class="MyProject.MyCursor"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Width="24" Height="24">
    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" Height="24" Width="24" Fill="White" />
</CursorBase>
```

The g.cs file is generated from the XAML and according to the XAML your base class is UserControl

Comment: you need to specify a XAML namespace for CursorBase

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that I was missing something fundamental like this

Answer (score 1):

Hey hi, @Jonny for me its working fine here is what i did, i think you messed with the namespace :

my project namespace is: SilverlightApplication2
Inside this project i created on cs file named CursorBase inheriting it form user control :

```
public class CursorBase : UserControl
{
    public virtual void MoveTo(Point pt)
    {
        this.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, pt.X);
        this.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, pt.Y);
    }
}
```

And then i created two user controls MyCursor.xaml and MyOtherCursor.xaml

xaml of MyOtherCursor :

```
<SilverlightApplication2:CursorBase x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MyOtherCursor"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:SilverlightApplication2="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication2" mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    </Grid>
</SilverlightApplication2:CursorBase>
```

cs of MyOtherCursor  :

```
public partial class MyOtherCursor : CursorBase
{
    public MyOtherCursor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And same for MyCursor :

xaml of MyCursor :

```
   <SilverlightApplication2:CursorBase x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MyCursor"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
 xmlns:SilverlightApplication2="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication2" mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    </Grid>
</SilverlightApplication2:CursorBase>
```

cs of MyCursor  :

```
public partial class MyCursor : CursorBase
{
    public MyCursor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into it Malcolm, I see my mistake now